# javascript closures onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript

Why the code is not parsed when I change

```
var comments_switcher = (function(){
    var switcher = null;
    var show = 'Show comments';
    var hide = 'Hide comments';
    function init(){
        if ( switcher == null ) switcher = document.getElementById("comments_switch");
    }   
    function switched_on(){     
        return switcher.value == show;
    }
    return {
        trigger : function(do_init){
            if ( do_init ) init();
            switcher.value = switched_on() ? hide : show;
        }
    }
})();
```

into

```
var comments_switcher = (function(){
    var switcher = null;
    var show = 'Show comments';
    var hide = 'Hide comments';
    function init(){
        if ( switcher == null ) switcher = document.getElementById("comments_switch");
    }   

    return {
            trigger : function(do_init){
               if ( do_init ) init();
               switcher.value = switched_on() ? hide : show;
            },
            switched_on : function(){       
               return switcher.value == show;
            }
    }
})();
```

And why `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` does not work when giving a function object instead of `function() {}`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem/question? I see no `onreadystatechange` handling...

Comment: It's just the theoretical question. You don't need any handling to answer it.

Comment: This whole thing makes zero sense.

Comment: @jsumners: The `switched_on` function was moved from a locally scoped function to a method of the returned object. But there was no change in how the `.trigger()` method was referencing the function.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean the question makes any sense. What is meant by "not parsed"? There's nothing invalid, so it should "parse" just fine. Why is `onreadystatechange` mentioned in the question but seemingly has nothing to do with the content?

Comment: "parsed" is definitely the wrong word here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `switched_on` method from the returned object since it's no longer a variable.

You can use `this.switched_on()`, assuming the `trigger()` method is invoked as `comments_switcher.trigger()`.

```
return {
    trigger : function(do_init){
        if ( do_init ) init();
        switcher.value = this.switched_on() ? hide : show;
// -----------------------^
    },
    switched_on : function(){       
       return switcher.value == show;
    }
}
```

But again, this relies on `this` being properly set to the returned object. This will depend on how you've invoked `trigger`.

---

If you did:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = comments_switcher.trigger;
```

...it will fail. You could change it to:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { comments_switcher.trigger() };
```

Comment: Yes, but this is my question :) I need to know why it fails.

Comment: @John: the first part of my answer shows why. You no longer have a local variable named `switched_on`, so there's nothing to reference. Since you moved it to the object, you need to access it as a property of the object. The last part of my answer is based on speculation, because I don't know how you're invoking the `trigger()` method.

Comment: switched_on was not variable, it was always a function. The first comment is about xmlhttp, but not the comments_switcher.

Comment: @John: The syntax is that of a function declaration, which effectively becomes a local variable. I'm not worried about minor semantic quibbles. If you're wondering what's the difference between the two `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` assignments, its because the first one detaches the method from the object, so when invoked, the method has no memory of that object. The second one maintains the relationship between object and method.

Comment: what if there's a function called f and the name f is assigned? In this case it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @John: I don't understand what you mean. If you declared a function `f` in the local variable scope, and then made that function a property of the returned object, then you could call it either way, but its `this` value may vary since the value of `this` is determined by *how* the function was invoked.

Comment: function f() {} xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = f; That's what I mean.

Comment: @John: Your function `f` will be invoked properly when the event happens. Don't know what the issue is. I believe its `this` value will be the `xmlhttp` object. Is that your concern?

Comment: when I use function f ()
 {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
   clearTimeout( timeout );
   if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
   {
  $("#data").html( xmlhttp.responseText );
  $("#comments_switch").click(
  function()
  {
   comments_switcher.trigger(true);
  });
  if ( fade_out ) $("#data").fadeIn("slow");
   } 
   else handleError( xmlhttp.statusText );
 } byt assigning xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = f; it does not work.

Comment: @John: "Does not work" is never an adequate description of an issue. And these partial examples don't provide enough information. Check your browser's developer console for errors. If you have an issue, please provide a complete example that is suitable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: function news_data(id, fade_out = false)
{
 if ( fade_out ) $("#data").fadeOut("slow");
 var xmlhttp = get_xml_http();
 news_id = id;
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "news.php?id=" + id, true); // asynchronous response
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
   clearTimeout( timeout );
   if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
   {
  $("#data").html( xmlhttp.responseText );
  $("#comments_switch").click(
  function()
  {
   comments_switcher.trigger(true);
  });
  if ( fade_out ) $("#data").fadeIn("slow");
   } 
   else handleError( xmlhttp.statusText );
 }

Comment: I replaced the function for the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange by a f with the same body.